# Making span zoom with the enclosed svg on zoom

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

I have an HTML page that has the following structure:

```html
<span class="svg-equation">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="17" width="32" wrs:baseline="13">
    <text fill="#333333" font-family="Arial" font-size="12" text-anchor="middle" x="20.5" y="13.5">222</text>
  </svg>
</span>
```

But when I zoom the page, the svg is zoomed but the span doesnot thus making part of the svg seem cropped. I want that the span should expand with the svg, such that the complete svg is visible at all times. How do I ensure this?

Comment: Can you add the CSS for the `<span>` ?

Comment: .svg-equation{
 border:0px !important;
 
}

Comment: Seems fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/x96Lvqyx/, you must have conflicting css.

Comment: Actually there was a {overflow:hidden} in the css on the svg. That is why it wasn't working